# Why additional " is adding to argument string with spaces when receiving a function as string using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spacing

I am using ajax to get StateName and StateID and display a picture with received StateName. Clicking on that picture will call a javascript function `callState(id,state_name)`. My issue is if `state_name = "Tamil Nadu"` is the received value, the function won't invoke. I come to know that the issue is with spacing. From console I understood that the function is called in the following form : `callState(1,'Tamil"Nadu');` - An additional `"` comes in spacing between Tamil and Nadu.

Below are my codes,
ajax redirect to processing_search_state.jsp page where I process and get the data.

```
responce = responce
                + "<figure> <a href='#'> <img src=../images/tim1.jpg alt='' onclick=callState("
                + id + ",'" + state_name + "')></a> <figcaption>"
                + state_name + "</figcaption></figure>";
```

AJAX :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("Received Data" + xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("sLocfigID").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
```

alert : Received Data will print correctly with out issues. Below is the alert

```
<figure> <a href='#'> <img src=../images/timl.jpg alt="
onclick=callState(2,'tamil nadu')</a> <figcaption>tamil
nadu</figcaption> </figure>
```

But on Console the value is:

```
<figure> <a href="#"> <img src="../images/tim1.jpg" alt="" onclick="callState(2,'tamil" nadu')=""></a> <figcaption>tamil nadu</figcaption></figure>
```

For your info:
These codes works fine If `state_name = Goa` or `state_name = Kerala` because these are one words or words without spacing's in it. It successfully invokes `callState()` function.

Comment: Can't you see that there is an opening `"` in your `<img>` tag that has no closing `"`? The browser will add it for you ... in the wrong place of course

Comment: @DnR I get values from state_name from database. Usual queries.
state_name = rs.getString(2);
successfully receiving 'Tamil Nadu' in state_name

Comment: @devnull69 - Sorry I didn't get the extra opening. If you are talking about 'alt' - That is single quote opening and close.

Comment: It is not ... try to select one of those single quotes with your mouse, you will end up selecting the one double quote that is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafa is correct that you are missing quotes around your HTML attributes, but it only causes a problem from the missing quotes around your `onclick` attribute, not the `src` (since it is okay to have unquoted attributes which do not have spaces in their values).

Add an escaped double quote (`\"`) here `onclick=callState("`, like so:

```
onclick=\"callState("
```

And here `"')></a> <figcaption>"` like so:

```
"')\"></a> <figcaption>"
```

Comment: Paulpro - Thanks a lot. So that was the issue. :)